# Mapping a backing field, that has a different type from the respective property, using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I need to persist this class on database using Fluent NHibernate:

```
public class RaccoonCity 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual DateTime InfectionStart { get; private set; }

    private IList<Zombie> _zombies = new List<Zombie>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<Zombie> Zombies
    {
        get { return _zombies; }
    } 
    protected RaccoonCity()
    {}

    public RaccoonCity(DateTime startMonth)
    {
        InfectionStart = startMonth;
    }

    public virtual void AddZombie(Zombie z)
    {
        _zombies.Add(z);
    }

}
```

The property has type IEnumerable to indicate that you shouldn´t use it to insert new items. The backing field is of IList to make it easy to insert new items from the own class.

Zombie is a simple class:

```
public class Zombie
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string FormerName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Infected { get; set; }
}
```

The map is the following:

```
public class RaccoonCityMap: ClassMap<RaccoonCity> 
{
    public  RaccoonCityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.InfectionStart);
        HasMany(x => x.Zombies)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

When I test this, the data is inserted in database, but the zombie´s foreign keys are empty, and the RaccoonCity instance has zero items on Zombies list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the relationship as `Inverse`, which means the `Zombie` and not the `RacoonCity` is responsible for maintaining the relationship.

Either add the corresponding reference to zombie and set it on the `AddZombie` method, or remove the `Inverse` (in that case, you'll see an INSERT with a null FK followed by an update).

Suggested reading: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany

Comment: Thanks! "Inversion" was not real clear to me. I thought that the class responsible to persists itself was the class himself. And "Inverse" puts this responsibility on other classes shoulders...

Comment: Exactly. I agree that the nomenclature is not the most intuitive, but it has its roots on the original Java Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Found a post about it: https://web.archive.org/web/20090831052429/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/08/15/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-3-mapping.aspx

> I had to implement the method
>   HasManyComponent by myself since it
>   was missing in the actual trunk of the
>   framework. That is, it was not
>   possible to map a collection of value
>   objects. But it has not been that hard
>   since the source base is really nice.
>   My changes will probably be integrated
>   into the framework soon.

And this one:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-3-mapping-relations.aspx